# How to have http server handle a post request?

Tags: ruby, http, post, webserver

I am trying to write my own http web server in ruby. Right now it can only handle GET requests. I want to add support for POST requests as well.

What should a http server do to serve a Post Request? Below is my code that parses the request_line to get the http verb. Once i know the verb is a post I am not sure what to do with it.

```
def handle_request(socket, request_line)
  STDERR.puts request_line 

  header_params = request_line.split(/\r?\n/)
  first_line = header_params.shift.split(" ")
  verb = first_line[0]
  if verb == 'GET'
    path = requested_file(request_line)
    path = File.join(path, 'index.html') if File.directory?(path)

    begin
      File.open(path, 'rb') do |resource|
        send_response(socket, '200 OK', {
            'Content-Type' => content_type(resource),
            'Content-Length' => resource.size,
            'Connection' => 'close',
          },
          resource
        )
      end
    #rescue permission denied error
    rescue Errno::EACCES
      message = "Permission denied"
      send_response(socket, '403 Forbidden', {
          'Content-Type' => 'text/plain',
          'Content-Length' => message.size,
          'Connection' => 'close'
        },
        StringIO.new(message)
      )
    #rescue no such file or directory error
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::EISDIR
      message = "The file you were looking for can not be found"
      send_response(socket, '404 Not Found', {
          'Content-Type' => 'text/plain',
          'Content-Length' => message.size,
          'Connection' => 'close'
        },
        StringIO.new(message)
      )
    end
  end

  elsif verb == 'POST'
######################################
  #NOT SURE WHAT CODE SHOULD GO HERE
######################################
 end
end
```

Comment: There's not a fixed thing a server has to do in response to a POST request. What do you want it to do?

Comment: Hey @FrederickCheung right now when i try to post my html form input to a action it downloads the file i am posting to and does not run the code inside of the file. Id like it to post the html form to a rb file and do something with the  params

Comment: Well if you go down the route of a cgi like interface you would stick parameters and so on in environment variables, execute the script and return whatever the script output

Comment: @FrederickCheung any chance you could give me an example? I would really appreciate it.